# Android is part of a Native mobile application?

Tags: android

have I understood this correct ? that I consider android is a native mobile applications ? please correct me if Im wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android applications can optionally be built with the `SDK` (or Software Developement Kit) to develope in java. To develope in Native languages such as C or C++ you would use a combination of the `SDK` and the `NDK` (Native developement Kit).

[NDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Native_development_kit)

[SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Android_SDK)

EDIT 1:

Directly from the phonegap website `by using standards-based web technologies to bridge web applications and mobile devices` Which in laymans terms is saying that they have a application that acts as an emulator that injects your html, css, and javascipt code into itself to have the feeling of a crossplatform application (Don't quote me).

Another solution I have heard of is XML which takes the same approach except it uses your xml code and converts it into the language of your patform (ex. iOS--> Objective-C; android--> Java) giving you the feeling of a crossplatform application. I believe the term native application, however, refers to the use of a native programming language, ex. C or C++, hence android native development kit (could be wrong).

Comment: In my project I need to compare android vs. HTML5 using phonegap so can you explain how they are related ? in my understanding i put android in native mobile application so its easy for me to compare native vs. phonegap have I understood it correctly ?

Comment: Thank you FeatheredOrcian I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @PhamDk why we are here; always come to stackoverflow for programming questions though be wary of your wording and how broad said question may be.

Comment: I will try to improve and become better in asking question, this is my first time and I really need to be careful next time =)

Comment: @PhamDk yes in fact I am the most experienced when in comes to asking bad questions. Keep it up!